# How do I disable an account with the ASP.NET Membership Provider?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using asp.net membership provider. and I need to block user account in case if the user post spam. How can I accomplish it using build in features of the Membership Provider.

Can I use IsLockedOut? If so how can i update it programmatically?

Thank you

Comment: no you cannot use isLockedOut, it is readonly. But you can use IsApproved as shown below in my answer.

Answer (score 35):

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser("Yourusername");
if(user!=null){
user.IsApproved=false;
Membership.UpdateUser(user);
}
```

Comment: That "unapproves" them. What are the ramifications of doing so?

Comment: If IsApproved user is false, user will not be authenticated. It is same as IsLockedOut but IsLockedOut is set automatically depending on invalid outputs. IsApproved is the only property that can be of use in this scenario.

Comment: Thank you I think it will work for me. Because its the best solution so far

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an exposed method to do so, but you can always code a sproc and a helper method to do that for you.

Alternately, code a loop to lock them out with programmatic code ;)

```
for (i=0;i<lockoutTries;i++) membership.login(username,badpassword_constant);
```

Comment: @Marc_s ~ It is a HORRID hack but it is easily programmed, even by someone who can't write code. The earlier method I suggest and the logic it involves is much saner. However it requires a little more work to maintain.